# Did Charles Schulz say, "All you need is love, but a little chocolate now and then doesn't hurt"?

Tags: quotes

The following saying is often attributed to Charles M. Schulz, or to one of the characters in his famous comic strip, *Peanuts*.

> All you need is love, but a little chocolate now and then doesn't hurt.

I won't bother to give links, because all you have to do is type the phrase into a search engine to get a kajillion hits.

But is this attribution accurate? I suspect that the answer is no. If the answer is no, then it might seem difficult to confirm that the answer is no, since Schulz's output was so prodigious. However, what I can say with confidence is that I have carefully read all 26 volumes of [*The Complete Peanuts*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Complete_Peanuts) more than once, and nothing remotely resembling this quotation is to be found in there.

That might seem to settle the matter, but it does not. Nat Gertler's [*Peanuts* book collector guide](https://aaugh.com/guide/) lists many books by Schulz, including some (such as the "*Peanuts* prose and picture books") with content not included in *The Complete Peanuts*. To give a random example, the aphorism, "Happiness is surprising your Dad by shoveling the sidewalk before he gets home" appears in *Happiness is a Sad Song* but not in *The Complete Peanuts*.  I haven't checked all these books, and getting hold of all of them is not a trivial task. Schulz also drew some non-*Peanuts* comics that are collected in the books *It's Only a Game* and *Schulz's Youth* (but I've checked these books as well and the chocolate quote is not to be found).

Moreover, *Peanuts* was licensed to many companies, so one could imagine (for example) a box of Whitman's chocolates or a Hallmark greeting card featuring both *Peanuts* characters and the chocolate saying.

So what I am hoping for is that either

- someone can find the phrase in an official *Peanuts* product (as opposed to some unlicensed rip-off), or
- someone can track down a plausible original source for the saying (whether Schulz or someone else).

As an illustration of what I mean by the latter option, sometimes you will see the claim that there is a *Peanuts* comic strip featuring Charlie Brown painting targets around an arrow *after* he shoots the arrow and it lands somewhere. In fact, no such strip exists in *The Complete Peanuts*, but in John Maxwell's book *The Winning Attitude*, one finds this passage:

> One day Charlie Brown was in his back yard having target practice with
> his bow and arrow. He would pull the bow string back and let the arrow
> fly into a fence. Then he would go to where the arrow had landed and
> draw a target around it. Several arrows and targets later, Lucy said,
> "You don't do target practice that way. You draw the target, then shoot
> the arrow." Charlie's response: "I know that, but if you do it my way,
> you never miss!"

No actual strip is printed in Maxwell's book, and if you read carefully what
he says, he does not explicitly claim that such a strip exists. Although it's possible that Maxwell heard the story from someone else, I think it is very likely that his book is the original source.

Comment: Is "I won't post a source because you can google zillions of references" a **notable** claim? The first search results page contains no "notable" claims but is evidence of plagiarism from all the other plagiaristic claims. It's equivalent to asking "Everybody knows that... Is it true?" Can you please find one of those links that is the notable claim? Or do 'notable sources' not actually make that claim?

Comment: @WeatherVane I sense that you are citing a skeptics.SE policy that I am unaware of. Is there some rule that I'm violating? I don't think that the situation is equivalent to "Everybody knows that..." because "Everybody knows that..." does not provide evidence that even one person knows it, whereas the search engine reveals that large numbers of people are selling products that prominently display the claim on their merchandise and attribute it to Schulz. Is it necessary for one of those claims to be "notable" in some sense (what sense?) before the question becomes valid?

Comment: @TimothyChow: Unfortunately, the (now deleted) answer that you commented upon turns out to have been written by a user with a reputation of generating unsupported answers with a generative AI. This supports our strict requirement for references.

Comment: I have a childhood recollection of small Peanuts books with an aphorism on one page and some Peanuts characters drawn on the facing page.  Here's an example including at least one facing-page photo: [Happiness is a Warm Puppy](https://thecharmedbookshop.com/listing/712684317/happiness-is-a-warm-puppy-by-charles-m)  I could see this type of quote coming from one of these books.  Schulz is listed as the author.  I can't offer any proof without finding the quote in question, but perhaps this is a stone as yet unturned in your search.  But I'm not sure whether there were more books like this.

Comment: Actually, the related books here seem to be of the same type: [Happiness is a Warm Puppy (Google Books)](https://books.google.de/books/about/Happiness_is_a_Warm_Puppy.html?id=KrwMz0AHrbkC&redir_esc=y)

Comment: @Kyralessa I agree with you. Some of these books are listed on [Gertler's website](https://aaugh.com/guide/ladages.htm), which I mentioned above.

Comment: The matter of **notable** is discussed in [FAQ: Must all questions be notable?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable) where @Oddthinking says "... to demonstrate either a lot of people have heard of the claim, or that some notable person(s) make it." So my earlier comment may be off.

Comment: On [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/30262-all-you-need-is-love-but-a-little-chocolate-now) this quote has 26661 likes. And many quote sites attribute it to "Charles M. Schulz".

Comment: I'm certainly having difficulties tracking it down. Limiting the google search by date, the earliest I can find one version of the quote is on someone's Facebook page, where it's attributed to "Peanuts" rather than Charles Schulz, from January 2001. That's the only place it's on the internet until it shows up on a blog in 2006, now attributing it specifically to Lucy. Something I find of note, though - one of the other quotes on that page is said by Lucy in the cartoon, but is actually by one of Sally's schoolmates in the strip! So maybe it's from the cartoon?

Comment: @Showsni Can you provide links to the pages you found?

Comment: @TimothyChow The facebook page doesn't seem to currently have the quote on, it only shows on [Google's preview of the results, here.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22all+you+really+need+is+love%2C+but+a+little+chocolate+now+and+then+doesn%27t+hurt%22&sca_esv=559959589&rlz=1C1GCEU_en-GBGB926GB926&sxsrf=AB5stBglQ1IP6R2GgOBGTHMS7Anwmto_4A%3A1692951203576&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1930%2Ccd_max%3A2005&tbm=) The [blog is here.](http://mypregnantpauses.blogspot.com/2006/09/i-love-lucy.html)

Comment: @Showsni Thanks for the links. As you say, the blog is not a reliable source. For example, the quote about crab grass and the quote about Christmas trees are due to Linus, not Lucy. But yes, it is possible that the quote is from a movie or TV show. I doubt it, because it doesn't sound like a quote from a TV show, but I haven't checked all the TV shows exhaustively, the way I have checked the strip exhaustively.